# How to validate Money in Laravel5 request class

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

My Validation class looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class PaymentRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = array(

                       'invoiceid'=>'required',
                       'recieved_amount'=>'required',
                       'ref_no'=>'required',
                       'date'=>'required',
                       'comment'=>'required'
                       );


    }
}
```

I want to validate `recieved_amount` as Money field Like if anything other than money is entered it should be validated

Can any one help me in this

Comment: What's 'Money'? Wouldn't it just be a number?

Comment: Make custom validation.

Comment: @Satisfaction yes it could be float I guess, But I don't know the rules to validate that can you help me out

Comment: If by "money" you mean "the format we express currency" it is related to the country you live in. It's not the same one thousand dollars in US than in Spain.

Comment: @aldrin27 can you post an answer how I can validate that , I was thinking of using regex but I don't have much knowledge about that how to use here

Comment: @Amarnasan I think for now If I can just validate it as numbers (Float,numbers) probably it will do

Comment: @Amarnasan actually... one thoushand dollars is the same in the US, in Spain or in any other country.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use this, for example (being 'amount' the money quantity):

```
public static $rules = array(
  'amount' => "required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/"
));
```

The regex will hold for quantities like '12' or '12.5' or '12.05'. If you want more decimal points than two, replace the "2" with the allowed decimals you need.

Comment: so I will add `'amount' => "required|regex:/^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/"` this line in my rules array , ANd will it work for both integer and float

Comment: Yes, since the point part is optional. But use the correct money format for your country (in US, for example they use a comma instead of a point)

Comment: The problem is my company uses both USD and Indian rupee also some other country currency Like UAE and Turkey , Thats why I am just adding a generalized validation

Comment: I slightly changed the regex to allow 1 or 2 decimal digits, take a look.

Comment: I would slightly change it again: `regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/` to disallow something like `.22`

Comment: Word of the wise, money should be stored as cents.

Comment: @zanderwar money sending to the server will never be cents. It's sent as "2.99" etc then your server converts to cents before saving to a db.

Answer (score 0):

or, if you allow `.25` type inputs, extend the above rule like this:

```
['required', 'regex:/^(\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)$/']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ "required", "regex:/^(\d+|\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$/" ]
```

The above one matches all the below patterns.

```
12
12.5
12.05
0.23
8.32
12.33
.33
.5
.09
```