# i want to add money format on my Laravel project

Tags: laravel

How to validate money format with decimal part.

My request would be like `12,133.00`. Well U tried but so far not good. I am a beginner.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $this->validate($request, [ 
       'price'=>'required|numeric',
    ]);
}
```

Well I didn't expect much.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
     $this->validate($request, [ 
        'price'=>'required|numeric',
      ]);  

    $product->price=Input::get('price');

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate Money in Laravel5 request class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624710/how-to-validate-money-in-laravel5-request-class)

Comment: @DelenaMalan No, not in this case he wants to format it. As in the data coming in shouldn't already be correct. He assumes you will just enter a number with decimal. 12356.1548 will then become 12, 356.15

Comment: That's not how I understand his question. He uses the word `validate` after all.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is to do is use the native php number_format() function.
Documentation located n this here link [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). What you want to do is as follows:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->price = number_format($request->price, 2, ".", ",");
```

- Where the first parameter will be the number you want formatted.
- The second parameter will be how many decimals you want.
- The third parameter will be how you want to separate the decimals.
- And the final parameter is how you want to separate the thousands.

You can even simplify it to just:

```
$product->price = number_format($request->price, 2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of Regex and try something like

```
$this->validate($request, [ 
   'price'=>"required|regex:/^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{0,2}+$/",
]);
```

This will check thousands, and decimals.

Should work for 1.00, 10.00, 100.00 1,000.00 etc, but will not validate 1000.00 with a missing comma.

Let me know if this works for you as expected.